# How to make Woocommerce REST API to accept per_page and page parameters to fetch top_sellers for given period

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I want to use a paginated query from WooCommerce REST API for fetching top sellers for a given period. In their official API document, I could not find any parameter which accepts page number or records per page kind of value.

After searching I found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56003440/1496518

Tried the following patterns:

```
https://TheSite/wp-json/wc/v2/reports/top_sellers?date_min=2020-02-05&date_max=2020-02-09&consumer_key=ck_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&consumer_secret=cs_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx&per_page=1&page=1

https://TheSite/wp-json/wc/v2/reports/top_sellers?period=week&consumer_key=xconsumer_secret=cs_x366xxxxxxxxxxxxx5dd9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&per_page=1&page=1
```

But, none of the above is recognizing `per_page` or `page`. Always returning all available records within the given period.

However, these parameters are accepted by `orders` endpoint.

I need to pass these parameters for other endpoints as well for a customized dashboard.
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: isnt it something like ```https://TheSite/wp-json/wc/v2/reports/top_sellers?per_page=100&date_min=2020-02-05&date_max=2020-02-09&consumer_key``` ect

Comment: Nope! Rearranging the parameters doesn't work either. I don't think reordering has any impact whatsoever. I am expecting exactly the same number of records to be returned between the date range. It always returns all available data in the given period!

Comment: I'm going to try and do some research for you, I remember a post about being able to set a Default per page value for all endpoints

Comment: Thanks a ton @Azurry for your help. :)

Comment: I had a look, It seem's with Reports It returns everything under the specific report. I also tried using the Filter to try and separate them sadly no luck, Same for paging them, Now this does not mean im giving up! but I do think while we look into this maybe open a Issue on the Actual github Repository.

Comment: Thank you @Azurry for your enormous help. Opening an issue in Github is a great idea. I will open today. I wonder why such an important feature is not present (yet) in all endpoints Woocommerce provide!